# Print auto-increment strings from Perl map

Tags: perl, auto-increment

This Perl script prints output like this

```
value value value value
```

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $content );

my @myvalue = $tree->findvalues('//html/body/center[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/following-sibling::td'); 

@myvalue = map {/^(\d+)/; $1} @myvalue;
print join(' ', @myvalue);
```

Instead I need it to print like this

```
foostring1:value foostring2:value foostring3:value foostringn:value
```

How do I prefix the values with an integer-auto-incremented string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-increment operator will do this for you. This is all that is necessary

```
my @values = qw/ value value value value /;

my $key = 1;
say join ' ', map { 'foostring' . $key++ . ":$_" } @values;
```

#### output

```
foostring1:value foostring2:value foostring3:value foostring4:value
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also check whether regex was successful in order to have desired content in `$1`,

```
my $i = 0;
@myvalue = map { /^(\d+)/ ? sprintf("foostring%s:%s", ++$i, $1) : () } @myvalue;
```